# REST API doesn't trigger DelegatingHandler, only swagger does

Tags: c#, .net, rest, swagger

I need to log request and responses in my c# API and I tried using a DelegatingHandler class approach.

I also have swashbuckle/swagger running on the API. The handler seems to work fine but it only triggers and logs for swagger calls. It won't trigger when I call any of the the API functions. It won't even trigger when accessing an image located in the server folder. But it will always trigger if the path is swagger related.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageLoggingHandler());
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new MessageLoggingHandler()
        );
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
       }
```

This is what I've got so far. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work with accessing to files, since it is only middleware for controllers methods. Try to call you methods directly - if your handler work. Then for logging requests to files on your server too you need check some "under level" logger for IIS